# Mount AFP Fstab

Tags: automount

I'm currently mounting my harddrive connected to my time capsule via cifs in my fstab on ubuntu, but i'd like to mount it afp for better speeds.
`//192.168.1.xxx/Storage /media/storage cifs password=mypass,uid=1000,,gid=1000,sec=ntlm,user 0 0`
Is this possible?